# How to decode japanese ideograph?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, character, decode

I'm copying the content of a JSON file to my MySQL database.
In the JSON file i have addresses like these:

```
1453 K\u00f8benhavn
Andr\u00e1ssy \u00fat 10
Sankt Peders Str\u00e6de 29
```

that are copied in db in the right way:

```
1453 København
Andrássy út 10
Sankt Peders Stræde 29
```

I use utf8_decode function in PHP to write data from JSON to database, but it doesn't work with japanese ideographes and some other characters. Why?
It writes "??????" instead of converting them... What could be the problem?

This happens with characters like these:

```
\u014D
\u5343
\u4ee3
\u7530
\u533a
\u5185
\u795e
\u7530
\u4e2d
\u592e
\u901a
\u308a
\u4e2d
\u56fd
\u8a9e
\u6559
\u5ba4
```

Comment: utf8_decode converts the character to an ISO 8859-1 character. There are no Japanese (or Chinese or Korean or Vietnamese) characters in the ISO 8859-1 character set. You can see the characters in ISO 8859-1 here: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/latin1.gif

Comment: So how to decode these characters?

Comment: Please post a working code sample. Also, are the characters escaped, like you posted them here, or raw?

Comment: Here is part of my code: http://pastebin.com/D2ADsd9T